# Chatbot open link in parent window

Tags: chatbot

I am totally new using Chatbot and I'm creating a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. Chat window is opened in an iframe.

I want to display a link in the chat message and open the link in the parent window itself (not in a new window or new tab). Is it possible to achieve this?

Otherwise can I automatically redirect to any url in my parent window from chat window?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 answers:

1: Yes, it is possible to change the parent window, or top window, to another URL. (Provided the browser's security mechanism allows it: eg. both pages are hosted on the same domain and no special security restrictions have been added to the iframe)
You can do this using javascript:

```
window.parent.location.href = '<url to browse to>';
```

Or html:

```
<a href="<url>" target="_top">Link</a>
```

2: When you change the URL of the parent page (the page with the iframe), your iframe will no longer be visible, since you are redirecting to a new page.
Since you will therefore close the iframe, and thus the chat window, this might not be what you want to do. My advice would be to use a new tab for links; this not only makes for a better user experience, but will also make it so you don't have to worry about security settings in browsers changing and then breaking your application.

Comment: Sources: 
Iframe sandbox attribute = https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

A tag target attribute = https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: How can I execute javascript in chat window?

Comment: That depends on how your application code is set up; could you share what you have already using https://jsfiddle.net/?